# Raw class(not derived from UnityEngine.Object) as a member variable in custom monobehaviour not releasing On GameObject Destroy

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok while I was observing for memory leakage
I found out raw(?) class instance(not derived from UnityEngine.Object) were not releasing properly.

```
    public partial class GCWMonitor 
    {
        private static Dictionary<Type, int> _counter = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
        
        public static int GetCount(Type type)
        {
            _counter.TryGetValue(type, out var count);
            return count;
        }

        public GCWMonitor() 
        {
            var instanceType = this.GetType();
            if (_counter.ContainsKey(instanceType) == false)
                _counter.Add(instanceType, 1);
            else
                _counter[instanceType]++;

            //if (instanceType == typeof(IntervalTimerGate))
            //  DebugX.LogError(instanceType.Name, _counter[instanceType]);
        }

        ~GCWMonitor() 
        {
            var instanceType = this.GetType(); 
            if (_counter.ContainsKey(instanceType) == false)
                return;

            var count = --_counter[instanceType];

            //if (instanceType == typeof(IntervalTimerGate))
            //  DebugX.LogError("~", instanceType.Name, _counter[instanceType]);

            if (count <= 0)
                _counter.Remove(instanceType);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class TestClass : GCWMonitor { }

    public class Test : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private List<TestClass> _lst = new List<TestClass>();

        [Button]
        private void Function()
        {
            _lst.Add(new TestClass());
        }

        [Button]
        private void Destroy()
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

I cached TestClass instances to the list of Test(Monobehaviour)
and the counter ascended properly.

but when I Destroyed the gameObject of Test(Monobehaviour)
the count did not descend which means the destructor not called.

I did tried calling GC.Collect() function after destroying the gameObject.
but didn't work

the destructor was called only when I added this script.

```
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _lst.Clear();
    }
```

This was a CHAOTIC mind blower.
because I thought destroying the GameObject will also destroy MonoBehaviour Script
and will release all the raw class instance(member varaible) references.

===So My Question is===
why does the instance(raw class) reference is remained after the gameObject is destroyed?
could it be a bug of UNITY??

or is there a settings that I should know?

I could put a release code on "OnDestroy, or some circumstances" every time.
But it feels something odd.

Comment: When using `static` in Unity beware - [thar be dragons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html).  Unity is a **CLR Host** whereby it can and will **zap** out the **Primary App Domain** along with all your objects **including singletons** not just during runtime but also whilst using the **Editor**.  See also _[Details of disabling Domain and Scene Reload](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html)_.

Comment: @MickyD but isn't the static only the dictionary itself which holds no references to the instances, only to a type and int counter? The issue seems to rather be that the instance is only released if `_lst.Clear()` is called => somehow the `_lst` instance seems to still exist and hold on to the `TestClass` instance after the `Test` component was destroyed

Comment: I think your `GC.Collect` just didn't work due to the fact that `Destroy` is actually delayed until the end of frame so calling `GC.Collect` right after it will not work. It works for me as expected when using `DestroyImmediate();` instead